# Login form submit to HTTPS url. Is it secure ? 

Tags: forms, authentication, https

I have seen  normal http websites which use an 'https' url for their login page forms. Can I be assured that the transaction is secure ?

Is there any way to confirm that the transaction is secure ?

Comment: Have a read about secure http. Perhaps use google.

Comment: example can be seen at http://fab.com/about-fab/

Comment: Riju you are not getting the point, your question shows that you have not done ANY research on the topic, go read up on it on Wikipedia.  HTTPS security is a very well documented topic, you don't need to ask questions about it HERE you just need to go read up on existing documentation, tutorials, and primers on the topic.

Comment: 1+ @Ahmed Masud, gee scary this question is been asked. A simple google search will give you all the information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot *absolutely* guarantee it with [just] SSL -- there are various vulnerabilities and attack vectors: compromised certs, the new SSL vulnerability (with monitoring assit), trojans, cookie stealing, buggy/compromised server, etc.

However, it is definitely the *minimum* precaution required for a "secure" login: I would not trust a site that *didn't* use HTTPS/SSL for such a transaction.

Happy coing.